# Dynamically create new array and add value to it

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-scripting

> for (( i=1;i<5;i++ )) do
>           arr$i[$i]=$i done

This gives me the error 
./test.sh: line 2: arr1[1]=1: command not found
./test.sh: line 2: arr2[2]=2: command not found
./test.sh: line 2: arr3[3]=3: command not found
./test.sh: line 2: arr4[4]=4: command not found

How to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it have to be on one line? Even when I changed it to `arr[$i-1]=$i` it only worked when not on one line (Your $i loop goes from 1-4 btw, and arrays start at 0 in bash afaik). Could you also explain what you expect the array to look like when populated? That might help give an accurate answer. Not sure if you want an array with 0-4, 1-4, 0-5, or 1-5

Comment: It's not the primary problem, but there needs to be a semicolon (or a line break) before `done`. But as for the primary problem: are you really trying to create five separate arrays, each with just one entry in it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `let` bash builtin keyword:

```
for (( i=1;i<5;i++ )); do let arr$i[$i]=$i; done
```